# add custom headers to external URL from the React application on click of href

Tags: reactjs

```
<a href={https://stackoverflow.com/} onClick={() => handleClick()} target='_blank'  rel='noreferrer noopener'> {value}</a>

let config = {
  headers: {
    userState: value,
    userName: value
  }
}

const handleClick= async () => {
  axios.post('https://stackoverflow.com/', data, config)
};
```

When i click on link i should able to see these headers under request header.

[image]

Please suggest if there is another alternative to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an `html <a></a>` tag with an `href` attribute you are navigated to the given `href` link.

You can use the `<a></a>` tag without href but it will not be displayed as blue link with clickable pointer.

The blue link style can be added with css - to read more -https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

And the clickable pointer as well with the css property `cursor: pointer;`

Semantically, the html `a` tag is used for navigating, not to get / post data. Maybe you need a different html tag and use `onClick` to fetch the data you need - it dependts on what is your purpose.